# UTF-8 Encoding converts Control Characters >127 to?

Tags: c#

I have binary file with alphabets, numbers and Special Characters and Control characters as follows.

```
ESC!€STANDARD + UNDERLINE
ESC!COMPRESSED + UNDERLINE
ESC!ˆSTANDARD + EMPHASIZED + UNDERLINE
```

i am performing the following.

```
string file = FileOpenDlg.FileName;
System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
string data = myFile.ReadToEnd();
byte[] sendCmd = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
```

This replaces €,ˆ etc whose hex value is >80 to ?. When i send this to printer it gives wrong answer.

How handle the these characters? Timely help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the encoding of text in your binary file? when you read the file, does the "data" variable  in your code contain string with a valid and proper characters (readable in VS debugger)?

Comment: Perhaps the printer is expecting ANSI codes, so you should try using `Encoding.Default.GetBytes()`. Or you might need to create an encoding for a specific code page if the printer's code page doesn't match the operating system's.

Comment: There's [no such thing](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) as binary file with alphabets. If it's binary, read and treat it as `byte[]`. If it's alphabetic, tell the stream reader what encoding it's in.

Comment: The Printer is Expecting ANSI file format..i tried using Encoding.Default.Getbytes(), even this replaces characters €,ˆ with ?.